# Can I add multiple grid in a single angular module?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and started working on it for a while where I've created a single module as

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute','ui.grid','ui.bootstrap']);
```

Here you might have observed that I've used **ui.grid**. And based on this ui.grid, I've created multiple controllers where my business logic exist. After a while I stuck with a problem where I happens to use **ngGrid** to one of my controllers. So I've tried this

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute','ui.grid','ui.bootstrap','ngGrid']);
```

the moment I use this, data which was appearing before disappeared now. I didn't understand what might have happened there.

My question is can I actually use multiple grids as I've specified in the above code? If not can you help in achieving my problem? what will happen If I use multiple grid in a single module?

Comment: why depending on both `ui.grid` and `ngGrid`, you should really dump `ngGrid`. it doesn't work when another element `<div ui.grid="gridOptions"></div>` is created?

Comment: @elaijuh but for one of my partials I have to to use ng-grid="gridOptions" so

Comment: can you show the html?